# iphone emulator access network settings

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I have a clean install of xCode on my MAC and it is the first time I launch an iPhone simulator. I need a network access to test an imported project but the network settings do not appear in `Settings -> General`. I only have three : `Keybord, International, Accessibility.`

I had a look to `iPhone Simulator -> Services -> Services` Preferences but didn't find satisfaction.

I also reseted content and settings.

I'm using iPhone simulator 3.0 and 3.1  in debug mode.

Comment: First of all you are using a too old simulator. Version 3.0 is back to 2009. You should consider updating to a more recent version of the sdk and developer tools.

Comment: The project I'm working with has been developed with xCode 3.1.2 and ios SDK 2.2.1. Do you think I can use older versions of code with no problem ?

Comment: The code is too old, you may have to do some modifications for deprecated properties and classes, but in general you should be ok. You cannot submit apps to apple for review with such an old sdk.

Comment: @Mr.Starck you might need some changes, but the 2.2.1 SDK is very old. Also if you need to submit to the appstore apple will require the iOS 6 SDK as a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

The simulator uses the OSX netwerk connect and there is are no setting for the network in the simulator.

Unlike android the iPhone simulator is not a emulated device, but als the app name suggest a simulator. All call to the iOS SDK are just translated to native OSX calls.

Therefor you will always need to test your app on real device, especially if you need to do any  network testing.

Also all app submitted to the App Store must be build with at least the iOS 6 SDK since they need to support 4" devices.

Comment: OK thanks for the advice. I had seen that the ios simulator used the computer connection, but in my case it doesn't work :/

Comment: Well there is no way to make it work, since there is no network connection in the simulator. As I tried to explain the the iOS simulator is just an app translation some of the iOS SDK calls to native OSX calls. (most things are just directly run on OSX except for the UI part). Thus there are not settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate network situations (for example EDGE speed, 3G speed etc) by using the network linker that apple provides with the developer tools. It is an extra donwload (free) and can be downloaded from [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-).

Comment: OK I'm gonna try this. Do you have the name of the tools because the link opens on the xCode download page with every possible download ;)

Comment: Hardware IO tools :-)